# Microsoft Surface 2 and booting off USB

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I'm trying to fix a Surface Pro 2, it says part of the OS has expired, so I grabbed a windows 10 ISO put it on a USB stick.  Held the power button and the Volume up and there are no BIOS/UEFI settings to boot off USB.
The screen only says
Trusted Platform Module
Secure Boot Control
Exit Setup

This has made a frustrating afternoon.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Disable secure boot in the bios, try again.

Comment: Secure boot isn't turned on, I turned it on and off and still same thing.